# MongoDB update multiple subdocuments at one time with different id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to make an update query for multiple subdocuments at once. From frontend I am sending multiple leadgenId like:

```
"leadgen_id": "1853447141682245",
"leadgen_id": "539323508125510",
```

I want to update all the subdocument inside lead that having leadgenId matched to above array. How can i Do that ?

I want to set the value of selected subdocument and add salesperson field like like
`"salesPerson": "63c139f044502fb5aff42fda"`

Document:-

```
[
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63bff5340d4e704dc919be75"
  },
  "appId": "851841552636187",
  "page_id": "102279349307892",
  "form_id": "1495160767680095",
  "leads": [
    {
      "leadgen_id": "1853447141682245",
      "date": 1673524532695,
      "email": "test@fb.comaa",
      "full_name": "<test lead: dummy data for full_name>",
      "LeadType": "NEW LEAD",
      "xyz": "iiccccccccccciiiii",
      
    },
    {
      "leadgen_id": "539323508125510",
      "date": 1673524560730,
      "email": "test@fb.com11",
      "full_name": "<test lead: dummy data for full_name>",
      "LeadType": "NEW LEAD",
      "xyz": "iiccccccccccciiiii",
      
    },
    {
      "leadgen_id": "928163618347326",
      "date": 1673525774538,
      "email": "test@fb.com",
      "full_name": "<test lead: dummy data for full_name>",
      "LeadType": "NEW LEAD",
      "xyz": "iiccccccccccciiiii",
      
    }
  ],
  
}
]
```

Expected Result:-

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63bff5340d4e704dc919be75"
  },
  "appId": "851841552636187",
  "page_id": "102279349307892",
  "form_id": "1495160767680095",
  "leads": [
    {
      "leadgen_id": "1853447141682245",
      "date": 1673524532695,
      "email": "test@fb.comaa",
      "full_name": "<test lead: dummy data for full_name>",
      "LeadType": "NEW LEAD",
      "xyz": "iiccccccccccciiiii",
      "salesPerson": "63c139f044502fb5aff42fda" //Salesperson field Added
    },
    {
      "leadgen_id": "539323508125510",
      "date": 1673524560730,
      "email": "test@fb.com11",
      "full_name": "<test lead: dummy data for full_name>",
      "LeadType": "NEW LEAD",
      "xyz": "iiccccccccccciiiii",
      "salesPerson": "63c139f044502fb5aff42fda" //Salesperson field Added
    },
    {
      "leadgen_id": "928163618347326",
      "date": 1673525774538,
      "email": "test@fb.com",
      "full_name": "<test lead: dummy data for full_name>",
      "LeadType": "NEW LEAD",
      "xyz": "iiccccccccccciiiii",
      
    }
  ],
  
  
}]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) like this:

This query set the elements where `eleme` is defined `$in` the array. So with this query you are telling mongo: "I want to update the element that matches his `leadgen_id` is either `1853447141682245` or `539323508125510` (i.e. is in the array). And that element will be searched into `leads.HERE` and setting the `salesPerson` field".

```js
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$set": {
    "leads.$[elem].salesPerson": "63c139f044502fb5aff42fda"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.leadgen_id": {
        "$in": [
          "1853447141682245",
          "539323508125510"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LrB6ewRBbOc)

Comment: Thanks J.F for your answer,but It's not working in my case getting error like Could not find path \"leads.0.salesPerson\" in schema. (when I  am sending response from backend(i.e express node mongoose))

Comment: Try with [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-uXbxj-r7Us)

Comment: geting this error Could not find path \"leads.0.leadgen_id\" in schema

Comment: Can you provide an example of your documents? Is `leads` array empty or does not exists in any document?